# fetch data from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables named user,fruits,fruits_like.

> user table has id,name,email etc fields.
>
> fruits table has id,user_id,name etc fields.
>
> fruits_like table has id,fruit_id and user_id fields.

Now i want to retrieve fruit details from fruits including count for fruit by user_id.

I tried below query but in that i only receive fruits which is liked by $user_id. I need to retrieve all fruits by $user_id.

```
SELECT f.id, f.date_of_eating, f.healthiness, f.comment, 
f.picture, u.user_name,count(l.id) as isLiked
FROM fruit f
LEFT JOIN user u ON f.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN fruit_like l on f.id = l.food_id
WHERE f.user_id = '$user_id' and l.user_id=''$user_id''
```

If i run this query i get all records that i want but i need to include like count for that fruit which i am not able to add in this query.

> SELECT f.id, f.date_of_eating, f.healthiness, f.comment, f.picture,
>   u.user_name FROM fruit f  LEFT JOIN user u    ON f.user_id = u.id
>   where f.user_id = '$user_id'

can any one please help me get this done?

Thanks

Comment: "but i need to include like count for that fruit which i am not able to add in this query" what does this mean?  Can you give us an example  with data?  Are you saing a user can like a fruit not in the fruit table?  Or are you saying you need All fruit from the fruit table to display for each user AND THEN show if they like  it?

Comment: Firstly, COUNT is an aggregation so it is natural that your data is collapsed into one row. Secondly, your database schema is questionable. Why whould you need a user_id attribute in your fruits table? And if your fruits_like table is some sort of realization of many to many relationship between the users and the fruits, why would you join the tables in such a weird way? Just join the users and the fruits to the fruits_like table. Finally, if you still want to keep your current solution, an inner query might be of of some use.